# Selenium Webdriver (Java): Why is it that my text link can't be found?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

This test was working yesterday but now all of the sudden it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to click on a text link.  Any help would be appreciated.

**My code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("ALEX")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>




    <div id="page">

<!-- include Header Start -->
            <a name="PAGETOP"></a>




        <div id="header">


            <div class="smallmenu" >

                            <a href= "BatchProcess.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Batch Processing</a> |

                            <a href="JobQueue.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SECURITY" title="Click here to view the job queue">Job Queue</a> |

                            <a href= "PDMain.asp?PPVS=CELL5572" title="Setup">CELL5572</a> |

    <a href="mailto:ITS@test.com?subject=CELL5572&body=%0D%0A%0D%0A______________________________________________________%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0ASite: CELL5572%0D%0APage: /btrac/Security.asp%0D%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ffrigg%2Fbtrac%2FSecurity%2Easp%3FPF%3DPDMain%26PPVS%3DCELL5572" Title="Send Internal Support Request">ITS</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="text" class="dataEntryObject" name="TBPARAM" value="Site Search" onclick="if (this.value=='Site Search') this.value='';" onchange="if (this.value) {window.location='pdsearchresults.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PAGE=SITE&TBPARAM=' + this.value;}">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="Site.asp?PPVS=CELL5572"><img class="systemAreaIcon" src ="public/images/icons/icon-home.png" alt="Home" title="Home"/></a>

                <a href="javascript:spawn_window('help.asp?PPVS=CELL5572','600','800','',0)" ><img  class="systemAreaIcon" src="public/images/icons/icon-help.png" alt="Help" title="Help" /></a>

                    <a href="logout.asp?PPVS=CELL5572">Log Out</a>


            </div>


            <div class="client_logo">

                <img src="images/_SITE/CELL5572_logo.jpg" alt="Group"   />

            </div>
            <div class="mainmenu" >
                <div class="topBorderLine"></div>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>

                    <!--[if IE]>
                        <td><div id="menuTitle" title="Benefits" >Benefits</div></td>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
                        <td><div id="menuTitle" class="reflected" title="Benefits" >Benefits</div></td>
                    <!--<![endif]-->

                    <td align="justify">



                        <ul class = "menuUL">
                            <li class = "menuLI"><a href="#">Resources</a> 
                                <ul class = "menuUL">

                                        <li class = "menuLI"><a href="ReconStatus.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">List Bill Audit History</a></li>

                                    <li class = "menuLI"><a href="news.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SECURITY">News &amp; Alerts</a></li>
                                    <li class = "menuLI"><a href="javascript:spawn_window('whatsnew.asp?PF=Employer&PPVS=CELL5572','600','800','',0)">Release Notes</a></li>

                                        <li class = "menuLI"><a href="javascript:spawn_window('Library.asp?PPVS=CELL5572','600','1000','',0)">Resource Library</a></li>

                                </ul>            
                            </li>

                            <li class = "menuLI"><a href="#">Tools</a>
                                <ul class = "menuUL">
                                    <li class = "menuLI"><a href="BillingAudit.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Billing Audit</a></li>

                                    <li class = "menuLI"><a href="EnrollTracking.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Enroll Tracking</a></li>

                                    <li class = "menuLI"><a href="Preview.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Preview Pending</a></li>

                                            <li class = "menuLI"><a href="Report.asp?PPVS=CELL5572">Report Factory</a></li>                                 

                                    <li class = "menuLI"><a href="SendSecureDownload.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Secure Download Center</a></li>
                                    <li class = "menuLI"><a href="upload.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY," target="_blank">Secure Upload Center</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class = "menuLI"><a href="#">Setup</a>
                            <ul class = "menuUL"  style="left: -106px!important;" >

                                <li class = "menuLI"><a href="MailRoom.asp?PPVS=CELL5572">Mail Room</a></li>                                    

                                <li class = "menuLI"><a href="colorsetup.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Site Color</a></li>

                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="Contacts.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Site Contacts</a></li>

                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="CreateNews.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">News &amp; Alerts</a></li>

                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="OpenEnroll.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Open Enrollment</a></li>

                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="Resource.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Resource Library</a></li>

                                <li class = "menuLI"><a href="Security.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&HST=SECURITY,">Security</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>



                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>    

            </div>            
            <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>


<!-- include Header End  -->

        <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>
        <br />


<!-- include Page Static Title Start -->



        <div id="pgTitle">

<!-- include BreadCrumbs Start -->               

    <div id="breadcrumb" >

    </div>

    <div class="divider">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="search_header" >

        <form method="POST" action="Search.asp" name="SEARCHFRM">
            <input type="hidden" name="HST" value="SECURITY," />
            <input type="hidden" name="PF" value="SITE" />
            <input type="hidden" name="PPVS" value="CELL5572" />
            <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0; padding-left: 10px;">
                <tr>

                        <td>
                            <a href="demedit.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&PF=SITE&TABLE=EMPLOYEE&NS=NEW&SK=NEW&HST=SITE," >Add Employee</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>

                <td>        
                    <input type="hidden" name="STYPE2" value="E" />
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="STYPE" value="ANY" />
                </td>
                <td>

                    <input type="text" id="QRY_header" name="QRY" size="16" class="search_header_input" value="EE Search"  onclick="if (this.value == 'EE Search') this.value = '';"/>
                </td>
                <td class="tdata" style="white-space: nowrap; border: none;">
                    <input type="submit" value=">>" class="commandButton" name="B1" />              

                        <label><input type="checkbox" id="allSitesSearch_header" name="ALLSITES" value="All" />Search All Sites</label>

                </td>

            </table>
        </form>     

            </div>

<!-- include BreadCrumbs End -->



            <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="titleTextNoShade">

                <h2>Security</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>
        <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>
        <br />

<!-- include Page Static Title End -->

        <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>
        <br />




        <div id="content" class="withTitle" >

<!-- include Notification Start -->

<!-- include Notification End -->

            <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- include Body-Cotent-Area Start -->
            <div class="relax">&nbsp;</div>

                        <form method="POST" action="SecurityEdit.asp" id="form1" name="form1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="PPVS" value="CELL5572">
                            <input type="hidden" name="PF" value="PDMAIN">
                              <input type="hidden" name="HST" value="SECURITY,">
                              <input type="hidden" name="SK" value="0">



                                  <table border="0" cellspacing="8"  width="99%">

                                               <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                  <td align="right">

                                                          <input type="submit" class="pbutton" value="Add New User" name="NEW">

                                                  </td>
                                              </tr>

                                  </table>



                                    <div class="tableholder" >  
                                    <table class="status textNormal noSort" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >

    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>
            <span>Active Users</span>       
            </h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="subhed">Name</th>
        <th class="subhed" nowrap>User Name</th>
        <th class="subhed">Email</th>
        <th class="subhed">Phone</th>
        <th class="subhed">Lvl</th>

            <th class="subhed">Role</th>
            <th class="subhed">Class</th>
            <th>Type</th>
    </tr>   

                                                <tr class="color1">

                                                    <td class="tdata" style="padding-left: 12px" valign="top">

                                                                <a href="SecurityEdit.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&SK=146887733&PF=PDMAIN&HST=SECURITY,">
                                                                    ALEX</a>

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top">ALEX</td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top">test0@test.com</td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top"></td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top">50</td>

                                                          <td class="tdata"></td>
                                                          <td class="tdata"></td>

                                                        <td  class="tdata" valign="top">Engineer&nbsp;</td>

                                                </tr>

                                                <tr class="color2">

                                                    <td class="tdata" style="padding-left: 12px" valign="top">

                                                                <a href="SecurityEdit.asp?PPVS=CELL5572&SK=242965156&PF=PDMAIN&HST=SECURITY,">
                                                                    ADMINQA8</a>

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top">ADMINQA8</td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top">test@test.com</td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top"></td>
                                                    <td class="tdata" valign="top">8</td>

                                                          <td class="tdata">Client Service Supervisor</td>
                                                          <td class="tdata">Base Class</td>

                                                        <td  class="tdata" valign="top">HR/Internal User&nbsp;</td>

                                                </tr>

 </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />

                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="8"  width="99%">    
                                        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                              <td align="right"><input type="submit" class="pbutton" value="Add New User" name="NEW"></td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </table>

                    </form>
```

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Because there's no link with the text `ALEX`. Only match is in some table row.

Comment: Chrylis, thanks for answering my question. I made a change in the source code so that Alex is a link. How would I access this element?

Thanks

Comment: Along the lines of @Saifur's comment, while I don't agree with his approach, I tend to think nearly everything important enough to be interacted with on the page (excluding dynamic content, such as search results) is generally important enough to get an `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like using `LinkText()` since it can break anytime with a little ui change or duplicate values addition on the page. I suggest you use `xpath`

```
By byXpath = By.xpath ("//*[@id='form1']//a[contains(text(),'ALEX')]")
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byXpath ));
element.click();
```

Note: Wait can definitely be a problem also. So try using some explicit wait before looking for the element.

**Edit:** Try action builder

```
By byXpath = By.xpath ("//*[@id='form1']//a[contains(text(),'ALEX')]")
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(byXpath)); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform(); 
driver.findElement(element).click();
```

Comment: I tried that out and it doesn't click on anything. It just sits there and the test "passes" but it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox.

I got it to work! For some reason, I need to scroll down to see the link first.

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space(text())='ALEX']")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

By the linkText(), the text that we are getting contains extra spaces, so we need to trim all those extra space and we do it by normalize-space(). You can use this function in another way as well. I do it by xpath.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("ALEX")).click();
```